# How to configure containerd to use a registry mirror?

Tags: containerd, docker-registry-mirror

If a system (e.g., a kubernetes node) is using `containerd`, how do I configure it to pull container images from a **registry mirror** instead of `docker.io`?

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to depend on version, but for 1.6+:

First, ensure that `/etc/containerd/config.toml` sets:

```
plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
```

Second, create `/etc/containerd/certs.d/docker.io/hosts.toml` (and intervening directories as necessary) with content:

```
server = "https://registry-1.docker.io"  # default after trying hosts
host."https://my-local-mirror".capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
```

(May need to restart containerd after modifying the first file? `systemctl restart containerd` Updates to the second path should be detected without restart.)

Note that earlier version 1.4 (e.g., in amazon-eks-ami up until a couple months ago) used a quite different method to configure the mirror.

---

If these changes are being automated, such as in a launch template user data script, the commands could be as follows. Note the escaping of quotation marks, and which side of the pipe needs extra privileges.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/containerd/certs.d/docker.io
echo 'plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"' | sudo tee -a /etc/containerd/config.toml
printf 'server = "https://registry-1.docker.io"\nhost."http://my-local-mirror".capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]\n' | sudo tee /etc/containerd/certs.d/docker.io/hosts.toml
sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

---

For more recent installations, may not need to modify `config.toml` (i.e. if default already set appropriately). Also, may not need to use `sudo` depending on where these commands are run from (such as in a launch template, for AWS EC2).